# How to mock specific methods and direct the rest of the methods to a particular implementation of the interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, xunit.net

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
    string Method1();
    string Method2();
}
```

This is an implementation:

```
public class FooImplementation : IFoo
{
    public override int Prop1 { ... }
    public override string Prop2 { ... }
    public override string Method1() { ... }
    public override string Method2() { ... }
}
```

I want to mock `Prop2` and `Method2` and for the remaining properties/methods I want to call the corresponding properties/methods in the implementation. Instead of descriptively mentioning a `Mock.Setup(..)` for each Property/Method, is there a straight forward way to achieve this?

Can I selectively mock the Property and Method and redirect the rest to the implementation?

Comment: Does `new Mock<FooImplementation>()` not work?

Comment: No. My `FooImplementation` methods are not `virtual`. So I cant mock any of them.

Comment: This is unrelated, but in your example Foo is declared an an Interface. However the name and implementation suggests that it is a class. Is this a mistake?

Comment: `Foo` is an interface. `FooImplementation` is a class.

Comment: It should have been `IFoo`.

Comment: In FooImplementation, the properties and methods are all tagged 'override'. Is there a base class from which FooImplementation inherits or is this an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Moq has a property called `CallBase` for this. So you can do:

```
Mock<FooImplementation> mock = new Mock<FooImplementation>();
mock.CallBase = true;
```

If you want a `Mock` of the interface type rather than the specific implementation, you can use Moq's `As` to get the correct type:

```
Mock<Foo> mock = new Mock<FooImplementation>().As<Foo>();
mock.CallBase = true;
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! I have one more addition to the question. What if `Foo` was an abstract class instead of an interface? `Mock.As` seems to support only interfaces. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @Sornakumar Well actually I don't think the `As` is strictly necessary for what you're describing. Have you tried the version in the first example?

Comment: Yes. I was not able to mock one of the methods because `FooImplementation` does not have any virtual methods.

Comment: @Sornakumar Ah, you're right. In that case I'm afraid I don't know if or how this could be done. The obvious workaround is to create an interface if you're able to. I would also say that having to do this at all may be a code smell.

Comment: Just thinking out loud. Isn't this a code smell? The moment we need to mock some and not all methods of the interface, could it be a pointer for interface segregation? The implementation of that interface is gonna end up with more than one reason to change and hence may break the single responsibility principle?

Comment: @Amol Yep, that's pretty much what I think. And the need for a dependency to have real rather than mocked behaviour for a test might also point to design issues like inappropriate intimacy.